# How do I include a blank line between files I'm concatenating with "cat"?

Tags: unix

I want to cat all the files in a directory, but include some spacer between each one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use awk

```
awk 'FNR==1{print ""}{print}' file* > out.txt
```

Comment: Nasty recursion. But this works: awk 'FNR==1{print ""}{print}' *.txt > /tmp/out.txt

Comment: what do you mean nasty recursion.?

Comment: If I run that line alone the command never quits, and keeps appending the files to the out.txt (which is in the same folder of the files I'm cat-ing.  Out.txt gets very large, very fast. (Again, OSX 10.5.8 YRMV).

Comment: file* in my example means processing files with file names starting with file. therefore if you have names like file1, file2, file3 then it will process. The only difference now is you change to *.txt.  I could only guess that you have MANY files with names starting with file?? If not, I don't see why it will into recursion and never quits, as it works for me. Anyway, since there's a work around for you, then should be fine.

Comment: EDIT-I'm a noob, and was doing `* > out.txt`, duh. Your answer is great (but not "cat", not sure I should select it as the "real" answer?). Thanks much.

Comment: `awk 'FNR==1{}{print}' file* > out.txt` worked better for me. Thanks.

Comment: @rahul286 How exactly does that work better for you? In my testing it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} \; -exec echo "-- spacer --" \;
```

Obviously, the 'spacer' can be more than the simple example used here.

Comment: Works, but I can't use "\n" as my spacer, it just uses a literal '\n'?

Comment: Just use `echo ""` for a blank line. I should have said the spacer could be more *or less* than the example.

Comment: sounds like you have a different implementation than mine. How about `echo ''` or just `echo` ?

Comment: The `-printf "\n"` "action" is also viable; I believe it also avoids invoking echo or any other subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to see `pr(1)`, which may do what you want out-of-the-box.

To roll your own, expand this posix shell script fragment:

```
ls -1  | while read f; do cat "$f"; echo This is a spacer line; done > /tmp/outputfile
```

This might more readably be written as:

```
ls -1 | while read f; do
    cat "$f"
    echo This is a spacer line
done > /tmp/outputfile
```

You don't really need the `-1` for `ls`.

Comment: Thanks! Just remember to redirect the output to another directory (as in the awk solution).

Comment: You don't need the `ls` at all. Just `for f in *; do cat ...`
(http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest way is using the `paste` command:

```
paste $(ls *) > file.out
```

Comment: Um, no, this just doesn't work. Paste does something similar but different to what the question asked. It interlaces the files.

Answer (score -2):

`echo "" > blank.txt

cat f1.txt blank.txt f2.txt blank.txt f3.txt`

To handle all of the files in a Directory (assuming ksh like Shell)

`for file in * ; do 

     cat $file >> result.txt 

     echo "" >> result.txt 

done`

Comment: That doesn't take care of all files in the directory unless you manually list them as parameters.

Comment: be careful if you cat like that with a for loop expanding everything. $file could be a directory and you will be catting a directory.