# Concatenating Files And Insert New Line In Between Files

Tags: linux, unix, cat

I have multiple files which I want to concat with `cat`.
Let's say

```
File1.txt 
foo

File2.txt
bar

File3.txt
qux
```

I want to concat so that the final file looks like:

```
foo

bar

qux
```

Instead of this with usual `cat File*.txt > finalfile.txt`

```
foo
bar 
qux
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include a blank line between files I'm concatenating with "cat"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653063/how-do-i-include-a-blank-line-between-files-im-concatenating-with-cat)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can do:

```
for f in *.txt; do (cat "${f}"; echo) >> finalfile.txt; done
```

Make sure the file `finalfile.txt` does not exist before you run the above command.

If you are allowed to use `awk` you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==1{print ""}1' *.txt > finalfile.txt
```

Comment: `AWK '{print $0}' *.txt`

Comment: This has the distinct flaw that there will be empty lines either at the end (from the first alternative) or in the beginning (second alternative).  You can easily guard against this with `awk 'FNR==1 && NR > 1 ...'` instead, though.

Comment: If you put `>finalfile.txt` after the `done` you can overwrite instead of append, which will remove the requirement to make sure the file is missing or empty before the loop.

Comment: Inspired by @timger, `awk '1' *.txt` :smile:

Answer (score 82):

If you have few enough files that you can list each one, then you can use [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) in Bash, inserting a newline between each pair of files:

```
cat File1.txt <(echo) File2.txt <(echo) File3.txt > finalfile.txt
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks.

Comment: This worked nicely for me for my Letsencrypt certs to create .pem files.

Comment: I'm trying to do it inside a xargs and this fails, any hint?
`… | xargs -I{} kubectl -n alex exec {} -- cat blah.log <(echo) >> blahblah.logs` cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory, command terminated with exit code 1

Comment: @tuxErrante I think the problem is not xargs but kubectl, which is taking a command to run remotely, while `<(echo)` is running locally.  Maybe `-- bash -c "cat blah.log <(echo)"`?

Comment: It dind't work on an alpine shell, but the following did, thanks for the hint! `sh -c "echo -e '\n\n' | cat - /../logs/a.log" `

Comment: Yeah, I'm working with files with different extensions, so this was right on the money!

Answer (score 42):

If it were me doing it I'd use sed:

```sh
sed -e '$s/$/\n/' -s *.txt > finalfile.txt
```

In this sed pattern $ has two meanings, firstly it matches the last line number only (as a range of lines to apply a pattern on) and secondly it matches the end of the line in the substitution pattern.

If your version of sed doesn't have `-s` (process input files separately) you can do it all as a loop though:

```sh
for f in *.txt ; do sed -e '$s/$/\n/' $f ; done > finalfile.txt
```

Comment: Or in GNU sed: `sed -s '$G' *.txt > finalfile.txt`

Comment: Only one stream! this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: be careful guys, I just crashed my PC because I used `find` in place of the `*.txt`, which meant the file was appended onto itself!

Answer (score 19):

This works in Bash:

```
for f in *.txt; do cat $f; echo; done
```

In contrast to answers with `>>` (append), the output of this command can be piped into other programs.

Examples:

- `for f in File*.txt; do cat $f; echo; done > finalfile.txt`
- `(for ... done) > finalfile.txt` (parens are optional)
- `for ... done | less` (piping into less)
- `for ... done | head -n -1` (this strips off the trailing blank line)

Comment: `for f in *; do echo -e "# ------ $f ------"; cat $f; echo -e "\n"; done` also print file name.

Answer (score 14):

You may do it using `xargs` if you like, but the main idea is still the same:

```
find *.txt | xargs -I{} sh -c "cat {}; echo ''" > finalfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I find `xargs` much easier to use than loops in bash.

Answer (score 10):

That's how I just did it on OsX 10.10.3

```bash
for f in *.txt; do (cat $f; echo '') >> fullData.txt; done
```

since the simple 'echo' command with no params ended up in no new lines inserted.

Comment: This puts the string at the end of the file; how do I get it inserted between _each_ file?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `grep`, with `-h` to not echo the filenames

```
grep -h "" File*.txt
```

Will give:

```
foo
bar 
qux
```

Comment: This command is the simplest and easy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In python, this concatenates with blank lines between files (the `,` suppresses adding an extra trailing blank line):

```python2
print '\n'.join(open(f).read() for f in filenames),
```

Here is the ugly python one-liner that can be called from the shell and prints the output to a file:

```bash
python -c "from sys import argv; print '\n'.join(open(f).read() for f in argv[1:])," File*.txt > finalfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A POSIX compatible solution is to use cat, but interlude each file with a file containing only a blank line.

```bash
nl=`mktemp`
printf '\n' > $nl
cat file1 $nl file2 $nl file3
rm $nl
```

A more fancy version might be something line.

```bash
nl=`mktemp`
printf '\n' > $nl
find file1 file2 file3 -print0 |
  xargs -0 printf "%s\0$nl\0" |
  tr '\0' '\n' |
  sed -n '$!p;$q' |
  tr '\n' '\0' |
  xargs -0 cat
rm $nl
```