# Merge Files in Folder with Blank Line in Between Each File's Content

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of text files saved in a folder. I would like to merge them into one file, say "all.txt", with a blank line in between the content of each.
I've seen this problem solved with bash [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183191/concatenating-files-and-insert-new-line-in-between-files).

How do I accomplish a similar feat with Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sourcePath = "C:\Temp\*.txt"
$destFile = "C:\Temp\all.txt"
$encoding = "ASCII"

Remove-Item $destFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

(Get-ChildItem -path $sourcePath) | 
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Content $_; ""
    } |
    Out-File $destFile -Encoding $encoding
```

Not must to say. The `get-childitem` is in parens to ensure the list of files is gathered before `all.txt` is created. Directories are then filtered out with `where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }` and the each file is iterated over. The iterator outputs the file content followed by a blank line. Finally, the whole pipeline is re-directed to `$destFile` with the specified encoding.

Comment: I tried it, and it gave me a file with the file names of all the files in the directory, with blank lines in between. I would like the content of the files, not the file names.

Comment: That is odd. It works for me, showing the filename and then the file content. Did you copy/paste or re-type?

Comment: Editied to remove the filename.

Comment: It turns out I just typed the path incorrectly. Works smoothly; thanks a lot!

Comment: To read a file, you have to know the character encoding it was written with. This code [assumes ASCII](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider/get-content-for-filesystem?view=powershell-6) for each. It's unlikely that text files are ASCII,  though the question asker would have to know.

Comment: The code makes no assumptions as to the encoding of the source files. It does force ASCII for the final output, but that's easily changed. I don't claim to be an expert in character encoding, but in a simple test of writing text files with different character encodings, PowerShell had no difficulty reading each one with a simple `get-content`.

Comment: (continued) - I do understand, though, that determining character encoding is far from trivial.