# How do I join two files on a newline?

Tags: command-line, cat

When I run `cat 1.txt 2.txt > result.txt`, I want `result.txt` to have a linebreak between the end of the contents of `1.txt` and the beginning of the contents of `2.txt`. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating Files And Insert New Line In Between Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183191/concatenating-files-and-insert-new-line-in-between-files)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include a blank line between files I'm concatenating with "cat"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653063/how-do-i-include-a-blank-line-between-files-im-concatenating-with-cat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many options is:

```
echo | cat 1.txt - 2.txt > result.txt
```

The - argument says 'accept standard input' and the echo provides the new line

This option only works cleanly for 2 files.  If you are actually looking at many files etc then for example:

```
(cat 1.txt; echo; cat 2.txt; echo; cat 3.txt) > result.txt
```

Would work;  It's worth noting this spawns more cat processes.